# How to count the number of lines where all fields have some value?

Tags: awk

Here's what my file looks like:

```
SRR008602 97 99 99 99 98 99  98  11
SRR009633 99 99 99 99 99 100 100 10
SRR022120 0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0
SRR026121 0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0
SRR008724 80 79 99 99 99 99 99   18
```

I would like to count the number of lines where columns 2 to 9 all have a value of "0". I'd prefer an `awk` solution. Here's what I came up with (and it works), but I am sure there must be a better way of doing it:

```
awk '$2 == 0 && $3 == 0 && $4 == 0 && $5 == 0 && $6 == 0 && $7 == 0 && $8 == 0 && $9 == 0 {n++}; END {print n}' input.txt
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

KISS in awk:

```
awk '{for (i=2;i<=9;i++) if ($i != 0) next; n++} END {print n}' file
```

Perl:

```
perl -anE '$n += 8 == grep { $_ == 0 } @F[1..8] }{ say $n' file
```

or (as suggested by Glenn Jackman) using the [List::Util](https://perldoc.perl.org/List/Util.html) module

```
perl -MList::Util=all -anE '$n++ if all {$_ == 0} @F[1..8]} {say $n' file
```

Comment: Alternate perl: `perl -MList::Util=all -anE '$n++ if all {$_ == 0} @F[1..8]} {say $n' file`

Comment: Works nicely; not allowed to vote, but still +1

Comment: Quick question: why does your awk statement has $i+0 and not simply $i ?

Comment: @ThePresident it's to force it to be evaluated numerically - however I'm having second thoughts as to whether that's actually helpful (since it will treat non-numeric fields as zero) - in fact going to change that now

Answer (score 1):

Slightly less typing in awk: compare the concatenation of those fields to concatenated zeroes:

```
awk '$2$3$4$5$6$7$8 == "0000000" {++n} END { print n }' input.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Slightly more succinct so long as your input data are already sanitized:

```
awk '$2+$3+$4+$5+$6+$7+$8+$9 == 0 {n++} END {print n}'
```

Comment: Out of paranoia, I'd explicitly compare each field to zero, otherwise you could have a false positive if, for example, $2 == -1 and $3 == +1

Comment: If negative numbers are possible in your data set, this is an entirely valid concern.  This was not made clear in your example input.

Comment: One can either assume that negative numbers cannot appear since there were none in the example; or assume that negative numbers are possible since there was no mention of them being impossible. In general, a more careful interpretation might be preferable, just to avoid errors.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cut -d ' ' -f  2- <file | grep -v '[^0 ]' | wc -l
       2
```

That is, first remove the first space separated column with `cut`, then `grep` for lines containing only zeros and spaces, then count these lines.

Or, using `grep` to do the counting:

```
$ cut -d ' ' -f 2- <file | tr -d ' ' | grep -cx '00000000'
2
```

Answer (score 0):

Another `awk` approach:

```
awk '{$1=""} $0 !~ /[1-9]/{seen++} END{print seen}' infile
2
```

Or in case you have more than 9 columns and you only want check 2~9:

```
awk '$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9 !~ /[1-9]/{seen++} END{print seen}' infile
2
```

Comment: I like the 2nd approach, as it gives me the possibility to work for a set of columns (e.g. 2-4 or 6-9 etc.). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With `grep`:

```
grep -Exc '[^[:space:]]+([[:space:]]+0){8}'
```